# R: gsub, match and remove

Tags: r, string-matching, gsub, regex-greedy

I have an dataframe `x`
where

```
x[1]= "red monkey"
X[2]= "blue whale"
X[3]= "Pink Panther"
```

and so on...(as it is a big data set)

```
color=read.csv("colors.csv")
color[,3]
Blue
Red
White
Grey
Pink
Red
Green
```

I have to match if `X[i]` contains any word  from `color[,3]`and if yes, then remove it.
i.e. the result should be another data frame like this

```
y[1]= "monkey"
y[2]= "whale"
y[3]= "Panther"
```

and so on..

How can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `x` is a vector,

```
gsub(paste(tolower(color[,3]), collapse='|'), '', tolower(x))
#[1] " monkey"  " whale"   " panther"

#to trim the whitespaces,
trimws(gsub(paste(tolower(color[,3]), collapse='|'), '', tolower(x)))
#[1] "monkey"  "whale"   "panther"
```